# how do I free this char** array?

Tags: c

I created this array:

```
char** command=malloc(sizeof(*command)*MAX_COMMANDS+1);
```

and after that every command[i] gets this:

```
command[i]=malloc(sizeof(*command[i])*strlen(token)+1);
```

How do I free the command 2d array?

Comment: Free `command[i]` in a loop, and then free `command`? What's wrong with this? It's just reversing the `malloc`s order.

Comment: iterate through `command`, freeing the entries, then free `command` itself. Don't leave an inaccessible array of non-freed pointers.

Comment: This is **not** a 2D array! A 2D array can  be `malloc`ed and `free`ed with a single call and is a very different type..

Comment: It is probably better described as a *jagged array*.

Comment: Could you not just use `command[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a rule of a thumb - each call to malloc corresponds to one call to free and typically you free the memory in reverse order of its allocation. In this case you should iterate over `command` calling `free` for each `command[i]` and only after that can you `free` `command`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   int i =0;
    while (i < MAX_COMMANDS)
    {
      free(command[i]);
      ++i;
    }
```

Comment: He asked about freeing "command 2nd array", so i assumed he did not want to free command itself, just its sub-arrays...

Comment: Fair enough (the original question wasn't completely clear), so +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
        char** command = malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                *(command+i) = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        }
        //memory allocated for 5 rows and 6 columns 2D array

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                free(*(command+i));
        }
        free(command);
        //memory is free for 5 rows and 6 columns 2D array
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: it'd be more easily readable if you did command[i] rather than command+i though.